# Quel emploi on fait du conditionnel dans cette phrase?

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical

> Le Premier ministre aurait annoncé une hausse des salaires de 5%.

Est-ce qu'on peut dire que c'est moins sûr que ''a annoncé'' ?

Dans une autre phrase, ''Si tu étais venu hier, tu aurais pu rencontrer mon ami Hubert.'' Est-ce que ce sont le même emploi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Niveaux de certitude

> Le Premier ministre a annoncé une hausse des salaires de 5 %.
>   (D'après ce que j'ai entendu,) le Premier ministre aurait annoncé une hausse des salaires de 5 %.

Dans le premier cas, on relate un fait dont on est certain. Dans le second, c'est un ouï-dire, sur la véracité duquel on choisit de ne pas s'engager.

Donc oui, on peut dire que **la phrase au conditionnel relate une certitude inférieure que celle de la phrase à l'indicatif.**

## Usages

D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel) :

> Dans plusieurs langues, le conditionnel est un mode employé pour exprimer un événement ou un état soumis à une précondition (d'où son nom), pour rapporter des faits tout en exprimant un doute à leur sujet.

L'exemple du premier ministre tombe clairement dans la catégorie « rapporter des faits tout en exprimant un doute à leur sujet ».

Le second exemple est différent :

> Si tu étais venu hier, tu aurais pu rencontrer mon ami Hubert.

Il n'y a pas de doute : mon ami Hubert était là, mais tu n'as pas pu le rencontrer car toi tu n'y étais pas. Ici, c'est un événement qui dépend d'une condition. Ce n'est donc **pas le même usage que dans le premier exemple**.